# object a = object b; what happens to object a?

Tags: java, math

One of my professor has given us a few practice questions for an exam, and one of the questions is something like the below (psuedocode):

```
a.setColor(blue);
b.setColor(red);
a = b;
b.setColor(purple);
b = a;
//what color is a, and what color is b?
```

It seems extremely rudimentary to me, so I've proposed the answer that a is 'red', and b is 'red', but I've been told this is incorrect. I've broken down my answer as I would a math problem:

```
a = 15;
b = 12;
a = b; //a becomes 12
b = 13;
b = a; //b becomes 12
```

But my thought process is through the mind of C, not Java. I figured there was some universal method for both, but perhaps I am wrong? Is my answer wrong or my professor is wrong? I'm very new to Java, although I have some command of C, Python, and web logic (PHP, Ruby), so I apologize if this is something trivial (which it is).

Comment: in the first example, `a` and `b` are objects, with a setColor method. In the second one, they're simple integer primitives. The two examples are NOT equivalent, because you're dealing with apples and oranges.

Comment: @MarcB, I realize this, but I thought irrespective of using math or colors, variable initialization should remain consistent.

Comment: doesn't matter if it's colors or the launch codes for a nuclear strike. assigning objects and assigning primitives have different semantics.

Comment: `a` and `b` are _reference variables_ that _point_ to objects.

Comment: why don't you simply setup the example in java and try it?

Comment: It is a crucial part of learning Java to understand the difference between reference types (objects) and primitive types (numbers), the difference between the reference and the value, and function calling scheme (like call by value and call by reference).

Comment: Try to see how this works : http://ideone.com/JHNLu7. The key is about object's references.

Comment: The color is purple, because they point to the same object on memory, so, when you change `b` you are changing `a` on the same time (modifying the object referenced by `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you've already created two objects, and made variables `a` and `b` refer to them, you've initially got something like this.

```
a -->  [ white ]     b --> [ white ]
```

Your first two lines change the colours of the objects, to give you

```
a -->  [ blue  ]     b --> [  red  ]
```

Then, you point the variable `a` to the object referred to by `b`, so that they both refer to the same object.  You now have

```
       [ blue  ]     b --> [  red  ] <-- a
```

Then you change the colour of the object referred to by `b`.

```
       [ blue  ]     b --> [ purple ] <-- a
```

Lastly, the line `b=a;` does nothing, because `b` already refers to the same object as `a`.

Answer (score 6):

It's because the fact that in first example, `a` and `b` are objects so this is what happens in each of the steps:

> a <-- is an object
>
> b <-- is an object
>
> a.setColor(blue);  <-- `a` becomes blue
>
> b.setColor(red);   <-- `b` becomes red
>
> a = b;  <-- **IMPORTANT**:: **original `a` object is released and available for garbage collection** and now **`a` holds the reference of `b` object**, which mean `a` and `b` are referring the same object now, which is `b`.
>
> b.setColor(purple);  <-- b is purple now. Since a points to b only, a is also purple

**Answer**: Both `a` and `b` are purple at this point.

Comment: What happens to the object that `a` referenced after `a=b;`? Is there no way to reference it now?

Comment: it will be garbage collected

Comment: @riista: `a` is available for the garbage collection as no variable in the above snippet is holding the reference of `a`.

Answer (score 4):

The important thing to realize is, after the line `a = b`, you don't have two objects anymore. You have two variables, both referring to the same object. So when you change that object's color, both variables reflect it. the line `b = a` actually doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, it's generally correct to think of any variable which is an Object as being a pointer to a value of that Object type. Therefore, the following in Java:

```
Color a = new Color(), b = new Color();

a.setColor(blue);
b.setColor(red);
a = b;
b.setColor(purple);
b = a;
```

Should do more or less the same thing as the following in C++:

```
Color *a = new Color();
Color *b = new Color();

a->setColor(blue); // the value a points to is now blue
b->setColor(red); // the value b points to is now red
a = b; // a now points to the same value as b.
b->setColor(purple); // the value BOTH a and b point to is now purple
b = a; // this does nothing since a == b is already true
```

(Note that this is **NOT** the same as references - as per [this article](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)).

Also note that, for primitives, Java variables are simply values - NOT pointers. So, in the case of primitive integers, it should behave more or less as you expect in your question, since `a = b` is setting the value of `a` equal to the value of `b`.

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are **references** to objects. When you write `a=b` then a is assigned to the reference that was previously assigned to `b`, so they now both reference the same object.

So, let's say you have two objects, O1 and O2, which at the beginning are assigned to `a` and `b` respectively.

```
a.setColor(blue);     // the object O1 is set the color blue
b.setColor(red);      // the object O2 is set the color red
a = b;                // a now references O2, and b still references O2.
b.setColor(purple);   // the object O2 is set the color purple.
b = a;                // b is told to reference O2, which it already is.
```

If you want to think through the mind of C, you can see `a` and `b` as pointers, that can be exchanged between variables and whose data can be modified.

It's not the same for primitive values which are handled like they do in C.

Answer (score 2):

Since everybody else has explained the difference between references and primitives I'll explain how this works under the surface.

So a reference to an object is essentially an number. Depending on the VM it will be either 32 bits or 64 bits, but it's still a number. This number tells you were in memory the object is. These numbers are called addresses and are usually written in hexadecimal base like so `0xYYYYYYYY` (this is an example of a 32 bit address, a 64 bit address would be twice as large).

Let's use your example from above using a 32 bit VM

```
a.setColor(blue); // Let's assume the object pointed to by a is at 0x00000001
b.setColor(red);  // Let's assume the object pointed to by b is at 0x00000010

/* Now the following makes sense, what happens is the value of 
   a (0x00000001) is overwritten with 0x00000010. 
   This is just like you would expect if a and b were ints.
*/
a = b; // Both a and b have the value 0x00000010. They point to the same object

b.setColor(purple); // This changed the object stored at 0x00000010 

b = a; // This says nothing because both a and b already contain the value 0x00000010
```

This should illustrate that references do work like numbers as you showed in your second example. However only under the surface, as far as you the programmer is concerned assignment of references don't work like assignment with primitives.

In Java you will never need to worry about the addresses of objects and the likes. In languages like C and C++ which enable lower level access this becomes more apparent and important.

**Arithmetics?** So can you do arithmetics and other stuff you can do with numbers? The shorter answer is no, not in java at least.

In C and C++ incrementing and decrementing pointers to objects is however perfectly valid and used a lot, for example to traverse arrays.

Feel free to ask questions if this wasn't clear enough.