# Why this code is not giving the output as expected

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I was expecting the output as AB , ABCD but the output is ABCD , B. How's that possible?

```
    public class Test {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
                 StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer("A");
                 StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer("B");
                 operate(a, b);
                 System.out.println(a + " " + " , " + " " + b);

           }

           static void operate(StringBuffer x, StringBuffer y) {
                 x.append(y);
                 y = x.append("C");
                 y.append("D");
           }
    }
```

Comment: have you debugged your code? You are aware you do have an x.append("C") in your code, so how don't you expect "C" in your a?

Comment: Unclear how I should answer.  I get your current output just by reading your code.  What is unexpected to you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you help me with the output as ABCD, B . I mean when we're inside the method operate then at the end of the method a and b value are ABCD and ABCD respectively but after the function ends its value become ABCD , B.

Comment: You pass `x=A` and `y=B` to the `operate()` method.  It then appends `B` to `A` on line one, giving `x=AB`.  Then `y=ABC` on line two, and on line three `y=ABCD`.

Comment: @Ankit you should be careful with descriptions like "global", as Java doesn't have global variables

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19504839

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So initially, you have this.

```
a -> [A...]         b -> [B...]
```

then when you call `operate`, you get two new variables referencing the same two `StringBuffer` objects.

```
a                   b 
   ->  [A...]          ->  [B...]
x                   y
```

Then you append the contents of one `StringBuffer` to the other.

```
a                     b 
   ->  [AB...]           ->  [B...]
x                     y
```

Then you append another letter to the first `StringBuffer`, and re-point the variable `y` so that it now references the same `StringBuffer` as `a` and `x`.

```
a                      
x  ->  [ABC...]        b   ->  [B...]
y
```

And you append one more letter, now referencing the first `StringBuffer` as `y`.

```
a                      
x  ->  [ABCD...]        b   ->  [B...]
y
```

Then you exit from `operate` and print out the contents of both `StringBuffer` objects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you think that `x.append(y)` return the new string stored in `x`, but it doesn't. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#append(java.lang.StringBuffer)), and see it just return the **pointer to x**.

Now with this insight, read your code again and see you understand the output.