# Insert into BST with recursion in java

Tags: java

New to Java. I learned BST tree insertion before with C++. But I try to replicate its recursive logic with Java like below:

```
public void tree_insert(Node x, int k) {
     if (x == null)
         x = new Node(k);
     else if (k < x.val)
         tree_insert(x.left, k);
     else
         tree_insert(x.right, k);
}
```

Suppose I have an empty tree

```
tree_insert(tree.root, 1);
```

But the root has not been changed.... I am guessing it may have to to with pass by reference in Java. But I am not exactly sure why it does not work. Some hint? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the whole pass by reference thing.  The `x` that's passed to this method is always a new copy of the reference, so setting it to `new Node(k)` inside the method won't affect anything outside of the method.

Comment: Return the root node. Whatever you do in the method, is local to it, unless you use a wrapper like `AtomicReference`. In general, modifying method arguments is bad news in Java.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem Thanks for the reply! Yeah, that is where I got confused. If we are talking about copy by reference, why changing one would not affect the other? Thanks.

Comment: When you write `=` after a variable name, you're changing what reference the variable contains; you're not changing any properties of the object that the reference points to.  My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19504839) might help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is assign a Node that has been passed by reference a new value. You already noted this and that is correct (I see that others stated this too).

How you would do this in java is by splitting up the recursion into two steps. **EDIT:** Not necessarily in java, but helper functions can be a good design to have in mind.

1. Introduce the insert function which null checks the root.
2. Private helper method that can generalise the insertion in the tree with recursive calls.

Here is an example:

```
public boolean insertBST(int value) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(value);
        return true;
    }
    return insertBSTHelper(value, root);
}

private boolean insertBSTHelper(int value, Node node) {
    if (node.value == value){
        return false;
    }

    if (node.value > value){
        if (node.left != null) {
            return insertBSTHelper(value, node.left);
        } else {
            node.left = new Node(value);
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if (node.right != null) {
            return insertBSTHelper(value, node.right);
        } else {
            node.right = new Node(value);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Since there can only exist distinct elements in a BST, we check for these to ensure that we don't insert the same element twice.

Hope this helps!